# Laravel Eloquent belongsTo filtering elements

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-routing

To start, my models look something like this:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    public function url() {
         return $this->belongsTo('Url', 'url_id');
    }
}

class Url extends Eloquent {
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

The relationship that is intended is that a `Post` has a `Url` and a `Url` has a `Category`, so a `Post` should implicitly have a `Category`. I am trying to write an Eloquent query to filter posts by `category_id`. I have a variable that is being passed into a GET route that represents the `category_id` and want to filter all posts by the `category_id` that is passed to that route.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `hasManyThrough` relationship may help you. [here in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through).

Comment: Like @MattBurrow, fetch cat and its posts, or better use `whereHas` on the `Post` itself.